# R: How to filter row as well as the ones before

Tags: r, filter, data-wrangling

I have a dataset that looks something like the following:

```
id  var
1  x
1  y
1  y
2  x
2  y
2  x
2  y
3  y
3  x
3  x
```

In this case, for each ID, I would like to filter for the rows where var=="y" and the row before it, but doing this only for the first y in each ID group. So the result would look something like:

```
id  var
1  x
1  y
2  x
2  y
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   slice(which(var=='y')[1] %>% c(.-1, .)%>% {if(any(!.)) 0 else .})

# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
     id var  
  <int> <chr>
1     1 x    
2     1 y    
3     2 x    
4     2 y
```